# Running a batch file from another batch file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, batch-file

I want to run Batch file 1(Path C:\3rdparty\Test\App) from Batch file 2(C:)
and VS2008.sln is there in C:\3rdparty\Test\App\VS2008

Batch File 1

```
REM BatchFile1.bat

set DEVENV_PATH=%VS90COMNTOOLS%..\IDE

REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------

set OUTDIR=.\output\windows\x86
rmdir /S /Q %OUTDIR%
mkdir %OUTDIR%

call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" VS2008\VS2008.sln /Rebuild "Release|Win32"
call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" VS2008\VS2008.sln /Rebuild "Debug|Win32"

REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------

set OUTDIR=.\output\windows\x64
rmdir /S /Q %OUTDIR%
mkdir %OUTDIR%

call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" VS2008\VS2008.sln /Rebuild "Release|x64"
call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" VS2008\VS2008.sln /Rebuild "Debug|x64"

REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------


echo "BatchFile1.bat completed."
```

Batch File 2

```
echo "Running Batch File 2"
call C:\3rdparty\Test\App\BatchFile1.bat
```

Here when batchfile1 is called from Batchfile2 it is not able to execute VS2008.sln since path is different.
I Don't want to change batchfile1.Is it possible to do changes in batch file 2 to execute the Batch file1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the directory to the directory of BatchFile1.

```
echo "Running Batch File 2" 
cd C:\3rdparty\Test\App
call BatchFile1.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added a local variable to your script that is set to the BatchFile1 path, whatever it is, so now you can use path relative to the BatchFile1 path.

```
REM BatchFile1.bat

set scriptPath=%~dp0
set scriptPath=%scriptPath:~0,-1%

rem now %scriptPath%  contain the script path, and then you can use command like
rem "%scriptPath%\MyCommand.exe" /MyParameter=123_abcd


set DEVENV_PATH=%VS90COMNTOOLS%..\IDE

REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------

set OUTDIR=.\output\windows\x86
rmdir /S /Q %OUTDIR%
mkdir %OUTDIR%

call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" "%scriptPath%\VS2008\VS2008.sln" /Rebuild "Release|Win32"
call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" "%scriptPath%\VS2008\VS2008.sln" /Rebuild "Debug|Win32"

REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------

set OUTDIR=.\output\windows\x64
rmdir /S /Q %OUTDIR%
mkdir %OUTDIR%

call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" "%scriptPath%\VS2008\VS2008.sln" /Rebuild "Release|x64"
call "%DEVENV_PATH%\devenv.com" "%scriptPath%\VS2008\VS2008.sln" /Rebuild "Debug|x64"

REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------


echo "BatchFile1.bat completed."
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put

```
pushd %~dp0
```

and

```
popd
```

around your code in batchfile1.bat

which would change the current directory to wherever batchfile1 is and then change back when you've done